# Monitor ECS docker instance with Prometheus

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, prometheus, amazon-ecs

I've deployed several micro-services to a docker container with dynamic port mapping, but now my issue is with finding the ports. How can Prometheus detect these dynamic ports?

Comment: Are you using any service discovery tools, like Consul, Zookeeper, etcd?

Comment: What do you want to monitor? The containers or underlying host?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am able to find out the solution here . Written one lambda which will invoke ECS cluster and services. will read all task from ecs service. task will have ip and port. then list down all ip and port supply to Prometheus as a target.json